# Can jQuery or AJAX listen for a variable passed over from another page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So i have a page for login and register. You click on either and a pop up appears, however if they sign in and its all correct I need the parent page to refresh (without using the body onunload as i have several directions the page can take). So can jQuery (or AJAX maybe) listen constantly for a variable or something to be passed over so I can do a window.location?

Thanks for reading =-)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: In terms of what sorry? In terms of a solution to the problem I havent got anything yet but i have a full relativity complex register and login system

Comment: You can write something relatively simply using `setInterval()` to regularly check for the presence of whatever you like at a regular interval, and perform whatever action(s) you need accordingly.

Comment: Is that putting stress on the server or client? My server cant cope with much i have pretty much maxed it out

Comment: `setInterval()` is a Javascript function, so it's purely running client-side. However, if you're submitting AJAX requests as part of the function passed to `setInterval()`, you'll be using server resources to handle them. I really can't be more specific in my answers with the question being so vague - if you can be more precise about exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish, I may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

in $.ajax() use the success setting to receive back a json encoded string or simple string result and process from there

like:

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "./API_PAGE.cgi",  
        data: dataObject,
        success: function(dataout) {
            //dataout should be string, json or single value;
        }
});
```

in php make sure you print your results.. that will send the data back, DO NOT USE return

```
<? 
...
   print $something;
?>
```